# Javascript library for a "Universal Wishlist" type bookmark-button?

Tags: javascript, bookmarks

Amazon has a [Universal Wishlist button](http://www.amazon.co.uk/wishlist/get-button) which can be added to the browser bookmarks bar, then pressed on any website and it sends the details of the page the user is currently looking at to Amazon. Amazon then pull out the product details out of the page and add the product to the user's wish list.

Do any libraries exist to replicate this (or similar) functionality for my own site? I could probably replicate it by copying Amazon's code using javascript, but don't want to waste my time if there already exists a library to do this or something similar that I can adapt. I'm also not really sure what this type of bookmark-button is called so it's difficult to google for.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a [bookmarklet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet).

Usually a link that loads a script in the current page.

```
<a href="javascript:(function(){var s=window.document.createElement('script');s.src = 'https://yourserver.com/your.js';window.document.body.appendChild(s);}())">
  drag this link to the bookmark bar
</a>
```

When you click the bookmark, it will execute the simple javascript code in the `href`.

A `script` tag is added in the current page. And load the url, here  `https://yourserver.com/your.js`.

At the end of the file `your.js` you can call a function to execute any action. You have access to all resources of the current page(DOM, JS and cookies).

Comment: Ok, that helps, thanks. Do you know of any libraries that take some of the grunt work out of writing my own? Either JS or Serverside code?

Comment: The javascript you have in the `href` of the code above is all you need to load the bookmarklet. The JS file you load, can fetch any library in the host page too, depending on what you want to do. eg: check if jQuery is there and if not, load it.